# Make the link to, and usefulness of, the tag wiki more obvious

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki

I finally decided to really look for a tag wiki one day on SO. I feel it should be more noticeable (though I'll admit it didn't take too long to find). I have always noticed the brief general description on what the tag means, but for a new user, the buttons below it seem, well, pointless. The `learn more...` should, in my opinion, say `View Tag Wiki`, or at least be slightly more prominent.

[image]

The whole tag wiki area has a nice border and is somewhat eye-catching. Most things on the internet that say `learn more...` have taught me not to click them. All the other "advanced user" buttons make the whole area a place to avoid for those who don't already use the wiki. This seems to discourage viewing the wiki (something that should be easy and is advised).

I would personally like the `learn more...` text that links to the wiki to be changed to something more obvious, and maybe even made **bold**, outlined, or moved away from the other options. At least such that a new member would easily notice the link, and feel that clicking it would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the tag wiki could use more visibility, but I don't think “View Tag Wiki” is the right solution. If you don't know what a tag wiki is, why would you pay attention to that?

I think “learn more...” is the right text, but it should be placed further up, at the end of the excerpt (with some suitable space).